# Android phone is not getting listed

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-11.04, sony

I have a sony Experia phone with Android version 4.04 and adb 1.0.31 running on Ubuntu 11.04.
I'm unable to list my phone in Eclipse/adb

My USB rules file is:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", ATTR{idProduct}=="5173", MODE="0666"
```

I tried restarting adb and USB service still it didn't work.

Comment: Can you see the device on dmesg? Can you see the device on lsusb / lsusb -v? Do you have the latest version of the sdk tools?

Comment: dmesg is not showing the phone but lsusb is listing the device "Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0fce:5173 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Android device is not listed while running adb devices (ubantu 10.10)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615145/android-device-is-not-listed-while-running-adb-devices-ubantu-10-10)

Comment: Thanks @Geobits the post you pointed helped finally.  I had to start adb in sudo and that made the trick for me.