# Why does Ubuntu 14.04 not recognize my Android device?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am sure this has been asked many times before, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117590/why-adb-ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-device) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615145/android-device-is-not-listed-while-running-adb-devices-ubantu-10-10). Still, the answers given are no help for me (I wonder why this whole stuff is not conveniently included in Android Studio. It would save a lot of time...).

Here is what I have done: After plugging in the device I used the command `lsusb` , which has one line in it as follows:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.
```

I 'assume' this is my phone, since it is a LG G3 phone. Then, according to the answers I have found, I have inserted the following line into the new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

The group `plugdev` exists and I am in this group (i.e. the normal user). 
Then I have rebooted the laptop, and made `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, but the command `adb devices` still gives the following output:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

How to fix this problem, so I can let AndroidStudio run the app on an actual phone?

Additional information:

- On the phone I turned on 'USB debugging' as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)
- Output of `dmesg` does not show any usb-related error or warning.
- Using different ports does not help.
- Using a different cable does not help
- Trying a different phone (Samsung) does not help either (after adding the Samsung-related line into the rules-file, restarting `udev`, etc.)

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging in the phone's developer options?

Comment: I think so. I tapped the Build number seven times and it gave a message that I am a developer now. Maybe I have to do this all the time? No I don't...

Comment: When you connect the phone, does it say 'USB debugging connected'?

Comment: No it does not 'say' this.

Comment: Go into the phone's settings. Select Developer options. Turn on 'USB Debugging'

Comment: I have. Please see updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93066/discussion-between-alex-and-andrew-fielden).

Comment: Please reconnect on chat, I had another thought

Answer (score 0):

The procedure described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) to make your phone run the app does not seem to be complete! It contains errors, which lead to unsolvable problems!!

Here is the solution: After the developer mode is turned on, a new menu "Developer options" appear. On then must activate "USB debugging" within that new menu! See also [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-connecting-lg-g3-to-linux-adb-aka-t2821673) for a more correct explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalled Ubuntu over previous install of it.  Connect USB (moto x Android and desktop Ubuntu), now it is recognized.
Have problems with Ubuntu, but a reinstall fixes it.

I don't trust hard drives to store my data, burn CDs now.  Hard drives break, operating systems may need to be reinstalled.  Flash drives can break.

If put Ubuntu and XP on same hard drive, while in ubuntu can copy and paste files from android phone to xp partition.
Windows doesn't recognize my smartphone but Ubuntu does, so I use Ubuntu to get files from phone to xp.